# Facebook Crawler not picking up my meta tag / Open Graph Object Debugger

Tags: facebook, html, meta-tags

Facebook crawler not able to read my metatags on

http://nitansh.fwd.wf/article/travel/best-all-inclusive-resorts-for-romance/3189783/

but it successfully read the tags for the

http://nitansh.fwd.wf/nurture/

Both are on made using extending same template base.html and by injecting metatags.html into them. you can refer the HTML code by inspecting element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While http://nitansh.fwd.wf/nurture/ shows the metadata even without having JavaScript enabled, http://nitansh.fwd.wf/article/travel/best-all-inclusive-resorts-for-romance/3189783/ shows only the following `head` when JavaScript is disabled:

```
<head>
    <script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/687271175.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

When you make the metadata available without requiring JavaScript, Facebook’s service will probably be able to parse it.

Comment: But i see different header when i inspect the page using my browser. what specific tool you are using?

Comment: @nitanshbareja: Disable JavaScript and check your page again. (I don’t know Facebook, so I’m not sure if they really don’t support JavaScript, but it seems likely that they don’t execute it for this purpose.)