# W3C validator : Element head is missing a required instance of child element title

Tags: javascript, html, title, w3c-validation

Hi am validating my HTML code through w3c validator. But it is showing an error Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.

URL is
http://nitansh.fwd.wf/article/travel/best-all-inclusive-resorts-for-romance/3189783/

while title is Present in the head of the html body

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>      Best all-inclusive resorts for romance- NowU
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/video-js.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/static/css/print.css">
  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js">
 </script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
 </script>
 <![endif]-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/socialsharing.css">
 <link rel="canonical" href="/article/travel/best-all-inclusive-resorts-for-romance/3189783/">




  <meta name="description" content="Whether for a honeymoon, anniversary, or private escape, these resorts fit the romantic bill.">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Whether for a honeymoon, anniversary, or private escape, these resorts fit the romantic bill.">


  <meta name="twitter:card" value="Whether for a honeymoon, anniversary, or private escape, these resorts fit the romantic bill.">



  <meta property="og:title" content="Best all-inclusive resorts for romance">


  <meta property="og:type" content="article">


  <meta property="og:url" content="http://nitansh.fwd.wf/article/travel/best-all-inclusive-resorts-for-romance/3189783/">


  <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/media/USATODAY/USATODAY/2013/06/18/1371593281000-Earlyne-s-luggage-1306181810_3_4.jpg"></head>
```

Comment: "while title is Present in the head" Are you sure?

Comment: yes you can check by inspecting element.

Comment: Post the head section of your code

Comment: There is, definitely, a `title` element in the `head` of the document.

Comment: I inspected your page head and there is most definitely no title element in there.

Comment: @BoltClock: are we looking at the same page? I can definitely see the `title` element in the `head` element (and, in the console, `document.querySelector('head title');` produces a/the title element.)

Comment: @David Thomas: No - apparently a redirect is occurring. I'm guessing the OP is trying to validate the source of the redirect, where the title element is most definitely missing.

Answer (score 2):

Just for your information this is what the validator is seeing in your code

```
<head>
<script src="//cdn.optimizely.com/js/687271175.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

You can see this by turning on the show source option in the validator. Maybe it's time to look into progressive enhancement?

Comment: yeah got the point, but why is this happening like am able to access the full page in my browser. But both facebook crawler and W3c crawler shows not opening the full page as in inspect element

Comment: @nitanshbareja if you close the meta tags with the trailing `/` do you get a better result from the validation? `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

Comment: page is not rendering when i disable the javascript, so W3C validator picks something else now am debugging what is it rendering when javascript is disabled on the page? :)

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23388252/1591669):

You are injecting the `title` element with JavaScript, but the W3C validator does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: Am not injecting it with JavaScript, the reason is still to debug am using django and running it in my local and forwarding the port using the forward utility :)

Comment: @nitanshbareja: Now your page is 404, but when it was still accessible online, the `title` element was only added with JavaScript. Without JS, your `head` only had 1 `meta` and 2 `script` elements.

Comment: Yeah I closed the tunel, but how are you debugging it ?

Comment: @nitanshbareja: Not anymore. I did it when it still was online. Disable JavaScript in your browser and view the source: that’s what the validator will see, too.